# Export Drive file Id to spreadsheet

Tags: google-app-maker

I have used the Drive Picker in my app. I want the user to pick a folder (just as the sample "Drive Picker"). Then I would like to take the ID of this folder and put it in a spreadsheet on the Drive.
Do you have any idea to implement that or a function which can make this?

Comment: Why do you need this? You can store doc id to model and then import the entire to spreadsheet at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, the missing ingredient is [Spreadsheet Sample](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/spreadsheet/).

```js
// onDocumentSelect drive picker widget event handler. Makes async call
// to server with selected by user document id.
google.script.run.appendToSpreadsheet(result.docs[0].id);


// Public server-side function
function appendToSpreadsheet(docId) {
  var spreadsheetId = 'spreadsheet id goes here';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  sheet.appendRow([docId]);
}
```

It is super basic example, you can go further, by handling multiple files selection and validating on the server side if the provided `docId` is valid Drive file.